# Java Обрезка пути к файлу

Tags: java, файлы

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Java можно реализовать следующий функционал.

Есть несколько файлов типа `File textFile`  (находятся, например, C:\Test\Folder1\text.txt, C:\Test\Folder1\Folder11\text2.txt)

Есть переменная такого же типа `File startDir`, в которой прописан абсолютный путь к папке (C:\Folder1)

К примеру, я получаю у файлов `textFile.getParent()`, что дает мне:

1. C:\Test\Folder1
2. C:\Test\Folder1\Folder11

Каким способом можно обрезать путь до папки, указанной в `StartDir`, чтобы получить следующий результат:

1. \Folder1
2. \Folder1\Folder11

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Comment: Тебе просто букву диска откинуть чтоли?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8555628/2293954)

```
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Path pathAbsolute = Paths.get("/var/data/stuff/xyz.dat");
        Path pathBase = Paths.get("/var/data");
        Path pathRelative = pathBase.relativize(pathAbsolute);
        System.out.println(pathRelative);
    }

}
```